# How to Set Mutiple Data Points in Line Chart

Tags: android

How Get a Value of All Data Points in Single Line Without Duplicate Entry of X Axis .How to Show a Multiple Data Points in Line Graph.
   This is My Code Which Display the Data on Single Line Please Help  Someone.

Comment: Have you used any third party library for display line chart?

Comment: yes  i am using     implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4' and Always Get a Data in Single Line Instead of Creating a Multiple Data Points

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: No but can you share little bit code than we got idea what exactly the problem is.

Comment: for (int j = 0; j < trafficFilter.dataPoints.size(); j++) {
            yVals.add(new Entry(trafficFilter.dataPoints.get(j).getY(), j));
        }
        set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "");
        iLineDataSets.add(set1);  LineData data = new LineData(xVals, iLineDataSets);
        mChart.setData(data);

Comment: Can you Please Help me

Comment: have you seen the demo of the MPAndroidChart  ?https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample

Comment: yes i already saw the Example on Git hub  but not able to implement